# FAQ page - broken image

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-faq

On the FAQ page under the "What if I see bad things happening?" section (https://stackoverflow.com/faq#flagging), the image URL points to:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/flag-post-link.png

This url does not resolve.

Comment: +1 for reading the FAQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blog was unavailable earlier today, that's why the image was unreachable. This has since been fixed.